# Using OR with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Arrayformula in google spreadsheet to tally the results of a sanitation survey.

I want to output the total number of times a set of conditions occur e.g:

has water storage AND only uses for water AND (storage has lid OR storage has spigot or ...)

the form I am using is:

```
=ArrayFormula( SUM(( 'Form Responses'!H:H = "has water storage" )*( 'Form Responses'!K:K = "only uses for water" )))
```

and I want something maybe like this:

```
=ArrayFormula( SUM(( 'Form Responses'!H:H = "has water storage" )*( 'Form Responses'!K:K = "nly uses for water" )*(anyoffthe following:storage has lid OR storage has spigot OR..) ))
```

how can I add the final OR clause without having to write out all combinations?

Thanks

Comment: Forget about the all combinations, it is not important... as for an example:

lets say there are 7 options: a,b,c,d,e.f,g 

I want to count the amount of times that a occurs along with either c,d or e or a combination of those three...

I am using google spreadsheet so countif doesn't help that why I am using arrayformula.
Using array it may look something like this:

    =ArrayFormula( SUM(( 'Form Responses'!H:H = "a" )*(c OR d OR e) ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the plus sign.  It treats the booleans as 0 or 1, so the sum of at least 1 TRUE will return TRUE.

```
=ArrayFormula( SUM(( 'Form Responses'!H:H = "a" )*('Form Responses'!H:H = "c" + 'Form Responses'!H:H = "d" + 'Form Responses'!H:H = "e") ))
```